# Azure Notification Hubs: How to send localized, platform independent push notifications to individual users from a .net backend?

Tags: .net, localization, xamarin.ios, cross-platform, azure-notificationhub

## The scenario

I am developing a backend for an localized, cross-platform mobile app and want to send push notifications to a user when some events occur in the backend.

The apps are developed for **iOS** and **android** using **xamarin** and the backend is a **web-api 2** that uses **Azure Notification Hubs**.

## What's working so far

Currently the mobile apps register for notifications through the web-API using [Installations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.installation.aspx). Registering via web-API is necessary, because the server creates a unique user tag which will be used to identify the user when sending messages. I am currently able to send test notifications to a registered iOS device from “Debug” section of the azure backend. Here is the code that handles registration:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CreateOrUpdateDeviceInstallation(DeviceInstallationModel deviceInstallationModel)
{
    var installation = new Installation
    {
        InstallationId = deviceInstallationModel.InstallationId,
        PushChannel = deviceInstallationModel.Handle
    };

    switch (deviceInstallationModel.Platform)
    {
        case "apns":
            installation.Platform = NotificationPlatform.Apns;
            break;
        case "gcm":
            installation.Platform = NotificationPlatform.Gcm;
            break;
        default:

            return BadRequest("The given platform is not supported");
    }

    installation.Tags = new List<string>{ OwnerId }; 
    //OwnerId is the server generated unique user tag

    await _notificationHubClient.CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync(installation);

    return Ok();
}


public class DeviceInstallationModel
{
    public string InstallationId { get; set; }
    public string Platform { get; set; }
    public string Handle { get; set; }
}
```

## My Problem

I now need to send **localized** push notifications when certain events occur in the backend. I am trying to achieve this **without the backend knowing anything about the apps’ locale nor the apps’ platform**. As far as I understood from the documentation ([Cross-Platform-Notifications](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-aspnet-cross-platform-notify-users/) and [localized-notifications](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-send-localized-breaking-news/)), **templates** will let me achieve this.

## My questions

1. How is the template registration done using Installations?
2. How must a template look like in order to be localizable on the client and what must a client do to achieve localization? (Or is there a template per locale?)
3. What must the backend do to send notifications while **not** knowing the clients platform or locale?
4. I have different messages (text) to send. Do I need one (or even more) templates for each message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to achieve the desired behavior.

For demo purposes, let's say the clients can register for two different notifications, MessageA and MessageB. *MessageA* is tagged from the client as *"tagForMessageA"* and MessageB is tagged from the client as *"taggedForMessageB"*. When the client app starts or the user changes it's language it calls the web-API and specifies **one** template for each message it want's to receive (messageA and messageB in this example). The Body contains the **platform specific, localized body**, for example:

***MessageA, english iOS***

```
{"aps":{"alert":"This is message A!"}}
```

or 
***MessageB, german android***

```
{"data":{"message":"Dies ist NachrichtB für Android!"}}
```

This enables the client to decide

- what messages it wants to receive
- what language the messages are in
- how it wants to display them.

---

### Registration through the API

Now here is the web-API code that handles the registration:

#### API Controller

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CreateOrUpdateDeviceInstallation(DeviceInstallationModel deviceInstallationModel)
{
    var installation = new Installation
    {
        InstallationId = deviceInstallationModel.InstallationId,
        PushChannel = deviceInstallationModel.Handle,
        Tags = new List<string>
        {
            //Obtain the users id from the database here
        },
        Templates = new Dictionary<string, InstallationTemplate>()
    };
    switch (deviceInstallationModel.Platform)
    {
        case "apns":
            installation.Platform = NotificationPlatform.Apns;
            break;
        case "gcm":
            installation.Platform = NotificationPlatform.Gcm;
            break;
        default:
            return BadRequest("The given platform is not supported");
    }
    foreach (var templateModel in deviceInstallationModel.Templates)
    {
        if (installation.Templates.ContainsKey(templateModel.MessageIdentifier))
        {
            return BadRequest("Message identifiers must be unique");
        }
        installation.Templates.Add(
            templateModel.MessageIdentifier,
            CreateInstallationTemplateFromModel(templateModel));
    }
    await _notificationHubClient.CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync(installation);

    return Ok();
}

private static InstallationTemplate CreateInstallationTemplateFromModel(TemplateModel templateModel)
{
    return new InstallationTemplate
    {
        Body = templateModel.Body,
        Tags = new List<string> {templateModel.MessageIdentifier}
    };
}
```

#### Models

```
public class DeviceInstallationModel
{
    public DeviceInstallationModel()
    {
        Templates= new List<TemplateModel>();
    }

    public string InstallationId { get; set; }
    public string Platform { get; set; }
    public string Handle { get; set; }
    public List<TemplateModel> Templates { get; set; }
}

public class TemplateModel
{
    public string MessageIdentifier { get; set; }

    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

#### MessageIdentifiers

This is a convention that the clients have to follow as well:

```
public class MessageIdentifiers
{
    public const string MessageA = "tagForMessageA";
    public const string MessageB = "tagForMessageB";
}
```

---

### Sending messages from the backend

And this code handles sending notifications to the client

#### MessageA

```
public void SendMessageA(int recipientUserId)
{
    var tagExpression = $"{recipientUserId}&&{MessageIdentifiers.MessageA}";
    _notificationHubClient.SendTemplateNotificationAsync(new Dictionary<string, string>(),
            tagExpression);
}
```

#### MessageB

```
public void SendMessageB(int recipientUserId)
{
    var tagExpression = $"{recipientUserId}&&{MessageIdentifiers.MessageB}";
    _notificationHubClient.SendTemplateNotificationAsync(new Dictionary<string, string>(),
            tagExpression);
}
```

Comment: You should really use templates for this purpose, it was designed for that. See Mimis answer...

Comment: @BarisAkar Actually, I AM using templates. If you know how to use ONE template for every message while keeping the backend agnostic of the client platform AND the client locale I'm all ears :)

Comment: sorry, I was not clear enough. You should use templates with template parameters to localize the notifications, as it is shown in the linked tutorial. I will post an answer...

Comment: @BarisAkar No, no, I got you. I do know how to user parameters in templates. I just did not get my head around how to do so, without knowing the clients locale on the server side.

Answer (score 2):

To answer 1-3, you will want to take a look at the [Template](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-templates/) feature. (Q1) Since you are using Mobile Apps, the Mobile Apps Xamarin SDKs actually allows you to [register with templates in Installations](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library/#register-xplat) directly. (Q2) To see what a template looks like in an Installation object, the body [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt621153.aspx) is a good place. (Q3) To send, the tutorials you've linked to actually provide great examples.
For Q4, it really depends. You can use the same template to communicate different messages given that all users registered with this template will receive these messages (e.g. in the [cross-plat tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-aspnet-cross-platform-notify-users/), you can easily switch in "Hello,"+user with another message). But if you need to have these messages be localized, etc, you will need multiple templates.

Let me know if you have any additional questions.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. How is the template registration done using Installations?

As you already used in your own answer, using the [`Templates`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.installation.templates.aspx#P:Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.Installation.Templates) property of the [`Installation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.installation.aspx) class.

> 2. How must a template look like in order to be localizable on the client and what must a client do to achieve localization? (Or is there a template per locale?)

Use template parameters for texts that need to be localized and add a language suffix to the parameter names. More precisely, the clients should register using templates with parameters that have language suffix.

iOS example with english locale:

```
{"aps":{"alert":"$(message_en)"}}
```

Android example with german locale:

```
{"data":{"message":"$(message_de)"}}
```

> 3. What must the backend do to send notifications while **not** knowing the clients platform or locale?

Simply send a template notification with all parameters in all possible locales.

Example assuming the app only supports english and german:

```
public void SendMessageA(int recipientUserId)
{
    var tagExpression = $"{recipientUserId}";
    var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "message_en", "This is message A!" },
        { "message_de", "Dies ist Nachricht A!" }
    };

    _notificationHubClient.SendTemplateNotificationAsync(parameters, tagExpression);
}

public void SendMessageB(int recipientUserId)
{
    var tagExpression = $"{recipientUserId}";
    var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "message_en", "This is message B!" },
        { "message_de", "Dies ist Nachricht B!" }
    };

    _notificationHubClient.SendTemplateNotificationAsync(parameters, tagExpression);
}
```

> 4. I have different messages (text) to send. Do I need one (or even more) templates for each message?

As you can see, with this approach, you can have one template registration per app instance and can send different localized messages from your backend.

Of course, the approach in your answer does also work, but you should avoid using tags if possible, since tag expressions are limited (e.g. [to 6 tags, if the expression contains other operators than `OR`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-routing-tag-expressions/)) and you are more flexible, if you don't hardcode the text for the notification into your app.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed example. I didn't know about the tag limit yet. 
I've still got a question: Can you use parameters inside other parameters? I.E. { "message_en", "Hello $(userName)! This is message B!" }.

Comment: @ChrisM, this is not possible. You could try to use [template expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn530748.aspx), but they are quite limited, so I would suggest you to build the strings containing the sender name in your backend, before providing them as template parameters to the send method. 
If you want to use template expressions, the iOS template could look like this: `{"aps":{"alert":"{$(messageBeforeUserName_en)+$(userName)+$(messageAfterUserName_en)}"}}`

Comment: Ahh yes, that's what I thought. Thanks for the clarification.